# Improve performance in Lat/Long geo location

Tags: sql-server

I have two tables, Bins and Locations, the first with 3 million records, the second with 30 million. I am trying to match Bin for Location with the following code

```
Create Table #tbl_locations (LocationID int not null, Lat float not null, Lon float not null) 
Create Table #tbl_bins (BinID int not null, MinLat float not null, MaxLat float not null, MinLon float not null, MaxLon float not null) 

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_locations] ON [#tbl_locations] ([Lat] ASC, [Lon] ASC) 
ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_bins1] ON [#tbl_bins] ([MinLat] ASC, [MaxLat] ASC) 
ON [PRIMARY]
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_bins2_ABC] ON [#tbl_bins] ([MinLon] ASC, [MaxLon] ASC) 
ON [PRIMARY]

Select L.LocationID, C.BinID
From   #tbl_bins C 
Inner Join #tbl_locations L 
ON (L.Lat Between C.MinLat And C.MaxLat) 
AND (L.Lon Between C.MinLon And C.MaxLon)
```

Unfortunately the performance is extremely bad, I have already tried to index the different fields but that did not help enough. Everything still takes more than 10 minutes to run.

Any idea of how can I make this perform better? Maybe a better matching algorithm? SQL Server 2012 SP3. 
BinID and LocationID already have a PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED created on them.
When I check the Execution Plan I see that the JOIN is performed by a NESTED LOOP.

The output of STATISTICS IO is

```
Table '#tbl_locations_________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000283'. 
Scan count 2631070, logical reads 25575057, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#tbl_bins________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000284'. 
Scan count 17, logical reads 14741, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Thanks a lot!

---

Edit - if instead of Temp Tables I use real ones, this would be the schema exported

```
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tbl_Bins]    Script Date: 5/30/2017 3:49:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Bins](
    [BinID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MinLat] [float] NOT NULL,
    [MaxLat] [float] NOT NULL,
    [MinLon] [float] NOT NULL,
    [MaxLon] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_Bins] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [BinID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[tbl_Locations]    Script Date: 5/30/2017 3:49:05 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[tbl_Locations](
    [ExposureID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Accgrpid] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LocID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Lat] [float] NOT NULL,
    [Lon] [float] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_tbl_locations] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ExposureID] ASC,
    [Accgrpid] ASC,
    [LocID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_tbl_bins1]    Script Date: 5/30/2017 3:49:05 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_bins1] ON [dbo].[tbl_Bins]
(
    [MinLat] ASC,
    [MaxLat] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_tbl_bins2_ABC]    Script Date: 5/30/2017 3:49:05 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_bins2_ABC] ON [dbo].[tbl_Bins]
(
    [MinLon] ASC,
    [MaxLon] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
/****** Object:  Index [IX_tbl_locations]    Script Date: 5/30/2017 3:49:05 PM ******/
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_tbl_locations] ON [dbo].[tbl_Locations]
(
    [Lat] ASC,
    [Lon] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

Comment: Just curious...how many rows does that query return?

Comment: Hey @hatchet , the query returns about 35 millions as you can have more bins per location. Cheers

Comment: Is it faster if you add LocationID to the IX_tbl_locations index?

Comment: Doesn't this produce a massive cartesian product? You have no criteria on `#tbl_bins` (BTW, drop the Hungarian Notation please) so you're going to get every possible combination of location and bin.

Comment: Sorry @hatchet I forgot to mention that both BinID and LocationID have already a PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED on them

Comment: @alroc the target of the join is to find to which buckets a location belongs - probably there are better ways to do it, I agree...

Comment: try running the query by discarding result set option and see how fast it completes,if it completes fast,then network might be your bottleneck

Comment: @TheGameiswar - no performance improvements with the discarding results option set.

Comment: Can you provide sample repro,you can script schema , statistics from generate scripts option.This way we can repro the exact behaviour you are facing

Comment: @TheGameiswar I added the STATISTICS IO - is that what you meant? The schema is what I described in the question.

Comment: I am sorry,that's not what I requested.you can right click database,go to generate scripts ,you can select tables,now in advanced tab,you can select options like schema , statistics,indexes...

Comment: If you provide the output I requested,we can repro the same behavior

Comment: I confirm this script involves just temporary tables. Any way I can export statistics from those?

Comment: I suspect an index on (MinLat, MaxLat, MinLong, MaxLong) will do the trick. In other news, this seems like a spatial query (that is "find things based on their position in the world"). Is there any reason not to use SQL Server's built-in spatial capabilities?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @BenThul I will give it a go. Do you think the SQL spatial stuff could perform well?

Comment: Sorry… lost track of this one. If your query is "find things within a certain radius of other things", the spatial queries can serve you well. It's definitely a different approach, though.

Comment: I will give it a go whenever I have some time. I am very interested to see how this can affect performance.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you run `update statistics` on the tables? What's the output of `explain` for this query?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way to improve this.

```
SELECT     L.LocationID, C.BinID
FROM       #tbl_bins C 
INNER JOIN #tbl_locations L 
ON         (L.Lat Between C.MinLat And C.MaxLat) 
AND        (L.Lon Between C.MinLon And C.MaxLon)
WHERE FLOOR(C.MinLat * 1000 ) <= FLOOR(L.Lat*1000) 
AND   FLOOR(C.MinLon * 1000 ) <= FLOOR(L.Lon*1000) 
AND CEILING(C.MaxLat * 1000 ) >= CEILING(L.Lat*1000) 
AND CEILING(C.MaxLon * 1000 ) >= CEILING(L.Lon*1000)
```

This helps the query by reducing the amounts of Bins to join to 1.

Comment: This doesn't look like a good solution - it's just a workaround until you solve your actual problem.

Comment: Unfortunately I run out of ideas and time :-/ I promised myself to give a go using spatial queries. Will keep this posted.

Comment: maybe you should try my answer then

Answer (score 0):

Create a *covering* index:

```
CREATE INDEX IX_tbl_lat_long_locations ON [#tbl_locations] (Lat, Lon, LocationID)
```

Having such an index means the table doesn't need to be accessed in order to retrieve the `LocationID`.

Make it a `CLUSTERED` index if you can.